# arduino gsm shield: AT commands for sending data to server(ip & port), not HTTP requests

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command

I have connected an arduino gsm/gprs shield on arduino uno. I want to send the data to a server(ip & port). They are not HTTP requests.
What are the appropriate AT commands sequence to send data to a server ? (not HTTP)
Highly appreciate if the AT commands are with their meanings.
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The AT commands that you need are in http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm .  TS27.005 from the same website has SMS-related commands.  Google individual commands to find examples of using the commands together.  Isn't there a demo on the arduino website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used an Arduino to connect to a website(xively.com) and send it data over a TCP socket.

I used the following sequence of AT commands:

```
AT+CGATT=1
AT+CSTT=[APN]
AT+CIICR
AT+CIFSR
AT+CIPSPRT=0
AT+CIPSTART=\"tcp\",\"api.xively.com\",\"8081\   
AT+CIPSEND (followed by '\r' and message)
AT+CIPCLOSE
```

You can find the meanings of these AT commands at
ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/IM120417009_IComSat/DOC_SIM900_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.03.pdf

The following link might help:
http://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/arduino-gprs-gsm-quadband-sim900